# How to uglify the assets for static html and bundle js at one go using webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a homepage(`index.html`) which is a static html with its assets, and after user login at the homepage, it will go to the second page(`home.html`) which is a react app.

**My folder structure is like this:**

```
--build/
----index.html
----home.html
----home.bundle.js
----assets/
------index.css
------index.js

--src/
----static/
------index.html
------home.html
------assets/
--------homepage.css
--------homepage.js
----components/
------home.js
```

**I want to use webpack to :**
1. minify the assets of `index.html`
2. bundle the `index.js` app.

**My questions are:**
1. What about I bundle all the assets of `index.html` rather than just uglify? Is this a better approach?
2. How to use Webpack to fulfill the above 2 requirements? I know how to bundle a pure SPA but don't know how to deal with this mixed type.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't uglify an html file (otherwise i will learn something today ;-)) but you can uglify your javascript to reduce the size and allow a better performance when they re loaded in the browser.

So what you can do for starting, it is too bundle all your javascript in one bundle file that you will insert manually in your html file. You can do it because in general we give a static name (e.g bundle.js) for the bundle generated by webpack.

Hope that s answering your question?

Romain

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. And sorry for the unclear, I mean minify the assets of `index.html` while still bundle all the js of the react app in `home.js`, could I do that via using webpack only?

Comment: Yes you can minify by webpack by using the right plugin. I dont remember right now the name but if you look for "webpack plugin minify" you will find it